# npm package to add event listeners when vue js component is loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I'm creating a personal NPM package that adds click event listeners to all elements that have the attribute 'foo'. It works completely fine on a static index.html file, but it says `document is not defined` when I try to use it in a vue.js component.

NPM package `index.js`

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[foo]');

// Loop through all elements
  for (let element of elements) {
    element.addEventListener("click", event => {
      console.log("It works!");
    });
  }
```

It works completely fine with `index.html`

```html
<button foo>Test Button</button>
```

However, when I try to do the same thing in the vue.js component.

```
<template>
   <button foo>Test Button</button>
</template>
```

it shows  `document is not defined` and says error occurs on 
`let elements = document.querySelectorAll("[foo]");`

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but you shouldn't mix VueJS and vanilla JS click listeners.

Comment: which *vue.js component*?

Comment: @ChrisG Any links or keywords that I could use to research for this topic?

Comment: Not sure, which topic exactly? What is the module supposed to do?

Comment: Put that code i the `created()` hook of a component.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yes, that will work. But the idea is that I want the npm package to do the magic, so all I need to do to simply add the `foo` attribute in the element.

Comment: You can't just do that because your npm package has no idea about when the DOM is ready as it's built by the VDom. You should be using a `directive` which your package registers and the user binds to their vue instance, so you can use `v-foo` instead which you can declare the `el.on('click'...` inside of the `binding`